# I was expecting segmentation fault or some kind of out of bound exception but did not get it when using command line arguments in a C program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments

I am learning C programming from "Learn c the hard way by Zed Shaw". He asks the learner to try and break their own code.

So I tried the following C code and thought printing more values that I gave argv will break it but it did not until later.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;

    printf("This is argc: %d\n",argc);
    printf("This is argv[argc]: %s\n",argv[argc]);

    printf("This is argv[0]: %s\n",argv[0]);
    
    for(i=argc;i<100;i++)
    printf("This is argv[%d]: %s\n",i,argv[i]);

    for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
    {
        printf("arg %d: %s\n",i,argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

**When I try to print argv upto 100:**
**I see the following when I was expecting some kind of out of bound or segmentation fault.**

```sh
./exp10_so These are cmd args
This is argc: 5
This is argv[argc]: (null)
This is argv[0]: ./exp10_so
This is argv[5]: (null)
This is argv[6]: TERMINATOR_DBUS_NAME=net.tenshu.Terminator21a9d5db22c73a993ff0b42f64b396873
This is argv[7]: GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/ab/.gtkrc:/home/ab/.config/gtkrc
This is argv[8]: _=/home/ab/Projects/learn_c_the_hard_way/./exp10_so
This is argv[9]: LANG=en_IN
This is argv[10]: GTK3_MODULES=xapp-gtk3-module
This is argv[11]: XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE
This is argv[12]: QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1
This is argv[13]: LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_IN
This is argv[14]: XCURSOR_THEME=breeze_cursors
This is argv[15]: XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
This is argv[16]: XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
This is argv[17]: SHLVL=1
This is argv[18]: TERMINATOR_UUID=urn:uuid:4496f24b-8a64-43af-ab5a-03fc7e722242
This is argv[19]: DESKTOP_SESSION=plasma
This is argv[20]: LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN
This is argv[21]: OLDPWD=/home/ab/Projects
This is argv[22]: HOME=/home/ab
This is argv[23]: KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5
This is argv[24]: USER=ab
This is argv[25]: TERMINATOR_DBUS_PATH=/net/tenshu/Terminator2
This is argv[26]: SESSION_MANAGER=local/tgh:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2372,unix/tgh:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2372
This is argv[27]: XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1
This is argv[28]: DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
This is argv[29]: XDG_VTNR=1
This is argv[30]: XDG_SEAT=seat0
This is argv[31]: LC_NUMERIC=en_IN
This is argv[32]: BROWSER=/usr/bin/firefox
This is argv[33]: GTK_MODULES=canberra-gtk-module
This is argv[34]: XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
This is argv[35]: XDG_DATA_DIRS=/home/ab/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
This is argv[36]: XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=KDE
This is argv[37]: VTE_VERSION=6401
This is argv[38]: KDE_SESSION_UID=1000
This is argv[39]: LC_TIME=en_IN
This is argv[40]: MAIL=/var/spool/mail/ab
This is argv[41]: LOGNAME=ab
This is argv[42]: QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
This is argv[43]: LC_PAPER=en_IN
This is argv[44]: PATH=/usr/local/nginx/sbin:/home/ab/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
This is argv[45]: QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=LVDS1=1;DP1=1;HDMI1=1;VGA1=1;VIRTUAL1=1;
This is argv[46]: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
This is argv[47]: SHELL=/bin/zsh
This is argv[48]: XDG_SESSION_ID=2
This is argv[49]: LC_MONETARY=en_IN
This is argv[50]: GTK2_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/ab/.gtkrc-2.0:/home/ab/.config/gtkrc-2.0
This is argv[51]: LC_TELEPHONE=en_IN
This is argv[52]: EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano
This is argv[53]: COLORTERM=truecolor
This is argv[54]: MOTD_SHOWN=pam
This is argv[55]: KDE_APPLICATIONS_AS_SCOPE=1
This is argv[56]: PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN=/run/user/1000/kwallet5.socket
This is argv[57]: KDE_FULL_SESSION=true
This is argv[58]: XAUTHORITY=/home/ab/.Xauthority
This is argv[59]: LC_NAME=en_IN
This is argv[60]: DISPLAY=:0
This is argv[61]: LC_ADDRESS=en_IN
This is argv[62]: PWD=/home/ab/Projects/learn_c_the_hard_way
This is argv[63]: XCURSOR_SIZE=24
This is argv[64]: TERM=xterm-256color
This is argv[65]: ZSH=/home/ab/.oh-my-zsh
This is argv[66]: PAGER=less
This is argv[67]: LESS=-R
This is argv[68]: LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
This is argv[69]: LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
This is argv[70]: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
This is argv[71]: (null)
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==69851==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000021 (pc 0x7f3c30d7b4c6 bp 0x7ffe273b2ba0 sp 0x7ffe273b22e8 T0)
==69851==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==69851==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x7f3c30d7b4c6 in __sanitizer::internal_strlen(char const*) /build/gcc/src/gcc/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_libc.cpp:167
    #1 0x7f3c30d0d057 in printf_common /build/gcc/src/gcc/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors_format.inc:545
    #2 0x7f3c30d0d41c in __interceptor_vprintf /build/gcc/src/gcc/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:1639
    #3 0x7f3c30d0d517 in __interceptor_printf /build/gcc/src/gcc/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:1697
    #4 0x562c5e03f290 in main /home/ab/Projects/learn_c_the_hard_way/exp10_so.c:13
    #5 0x7f3c30b0ab24 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x27b24)
    #6 0x562c5e03f0bd in _start (/home/ab/Projects/learn_c_the_hard_way/exp10_so+0x10bd)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV /build/gcc/src/gcc/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_libc.cpp:167 in __sanitizer::internal_strlen(char const*)
==69851==ABORTING
```

Comment: C have no bounds checking. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior* which *may* crash, but it may also seem to work, or it might set your cat on fire.

Comment: C is like flying an old plane. There's nothing to stop you from going straight into a mountain. **You must pay attention at all times to exactly what you are doing**.

Comment: It looks like your platform happened to put the environment variables following the command-line arguments, but there's no guarantee that this will happen. You did get a segfault at the end after the environment variables.

Comment: By the way, `argv[argc]` is *always* a null pointer. That's in the C specification. That you print this null pointer is in itself UB.

Comment: How unlucky can you get? Mine only got as far as `This is argv[1]: (null)` but that was only because the MSVC is polite enough to output `(null)` instead of trying to dereference `NULL`. Following `argv[argc]` the array values are indeterminate.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude and others for taking the time out to clear it up for me. Now I have a better understanding of the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *segmentation fault* happens when the code try to access a memory region that is not available.

Accessing an array out of bounds doesn't means that the memory before or after the area occupied by the array is not available: The compiler or the runtime usually put all varibales or *data* in general in a given block of memory. If your array is the last item of such a memory block, the accessing it with a to big index *will* produce a *Segmentaion Fault* but is the array is in the middle of the memory block, you will just access memory used for other data, giving unexpected result and undefined behavior.

If the array (In may example, but valid for anything) is written, accessing available memory will not produce a *segmentation fault* but will overwrite something else. It **may** produce unexpected results or crash or segmentation fault later! This kind of bug is frequently very difficult to find because the unexpected result/behavior looks completely independent of the root cause.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out. Helps in understanding things better.